# Tuples in NoSQL the same as RDBMS?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rdbms, nosql

I know RDBMS have the concept of tuples (that are, from what I understand, unordered rows of data).

I also learned that some NoSQL Databases use key value stores or tuples to store data.

If both NoSQL and RDBMS use tuples, do they have the same definition?

If they do, what would differentiate an RDBMS and a NoSQL database that uses Tuples to store data?

Answer (score -1):

The different NoSql database use different methods to store data. Nosql Database like Couchdb, store data as JSON File where you do not have any predefined schema while Nosql like Oracle NOSQL use both tuple storage(TableAPI) and JSON (Key/value API) to store data.

While we have tuples in Oracle NoSQL, they have a defined schema but the fields values can changes.

Say you have a field where you store an array of data. You just Define that filed while creating table but you do not need to Inform about the length of Array field.
Similarly If you have a Person table, now you need to store 4 different Address for that person Say Person1 and another person who has just 2 Different address.
In NoSQL, you can store these as ParentTable.childTable, without defining how many addresses a person has.

Person1 ---> 4 Different Address (Dynamic)
Person2 ---> 2 Different Address (Dynamic)

I do not need to worry about the Different numbers of address of each person. You just need to create  a person table (Parent table) and a person.adrress table (child table). that's it

Hope I was able to give you an Idea about tuples in Nosql. Let me know If you need some clarity.